# Start and End Selection in textbox - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

How to determine the end point of text selection in the text box?
for example: Start of 3 and select to 5 character in textbox1. 
00**000**00
(*Selection with the ability to edit selected text.*)

[image]

```
Private Sub textbox1_change()
If TextBox1.TextLength = 7 Then
  With TextBox1
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart = 2
    .SelLength = Len(.Text)
  End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How about you take the input as string and then use middle to manipulate the string? Or do you just want to have it highlighted?

Comment: Hi Ricars Porins! Selection with the ability to edit selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Text`.SelLength = Len(.Text)` , insert `.SelLength = 3`.